# Combine two strings - Special case

Tags: php, echo

I have all my text defined in separated language files, meaning if I write:

Example 1 (working):

```
echo TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_TENNIS;
```

The text defined depending on your language for TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_TENNIS is shown on the site (for example: "Great tennis products!".

BUT if I try to combine two strings in order to create and echo TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_TENNIS, it is not working. Instead of picking up the text from the language file, it just echoes "TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_TENNIS" on my site:

Example 2 (not working):

```
$first_part = TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_;
$products_name = TENNIS;
echo $first_part.$products_name;
```

Why can't I combine two strings like this, so that the text defined in the language file is showing as it does in my first example?

Comment: If you have turned error messages on, you get a warning or a notice saying "Use of undefined constant". You actually just echo "TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_TENNIS", to echo the constants TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT.'_'.TENNIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here goes your solution :-

```
define('TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_TENNIS','dfbvzdfb');
$first_part = 'TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_';
$products_name = 'TENNIS';
echo constant($first_part.$products_name);
```

you first defined a constant and the defined two variable with string value then print it,how the php differentiate between these two.

**note : constant called without '$' sign.**

Comment: Thanks, it's working! It was the constant() part that did it. Never heard of that before, but now I know better.

Comment: @user2157236 that the part where stackoverflow comes...its help to share knowledge across worldwide.

Answer (score 0):

Example 2 didn't work because you'd defined whole TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_TENNIS

try to use array for your project
like :

```
$array = array('TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_TENNIS' => "something" , ... and so on);
```

then use your code:

```
$first_part = 'TEXT_FOR_PRODUCT_';
$products_name = 'TENNIS';
echo $array[$first_part.$products_name];
```